# (PHP Filament) How to disable the default dashboard?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-10, laravel-filament

*First question*

I am currently learning PHP-Fiament and I can not figure out how to disable the default-dashboard.

My other question is:
Why isnt the Stack below centered?

```
public static function table(Table $table): Table
    {
        return $table
            ->columns([
                Split::make([
                    TextColumn::make('lastname')
                        ->sortable()
                        ->searchable()
                        ->placeholder('none')
                        ->label(__('messages.lastname')),
                    Stack::make([
                        TextColumn::make('phone_number')
                            ->sortable()
                            ->searchable()
                            ->placeholder('none')
                            ->label(__('messages.phone_number'))
                            ->url(fn($record) => "tel:{$record->phone_number}")
                            ->icon('fas-phone-volume'),
                        TextColumn::make('email')
                            ->sortable()
                            ->searchable()
                            ->placeholder('none')
                            ->label(__('messages.email'))
                            ->url(fn($record) => "mailto:{$record->email}")
                            ->icon('fas-envelope')
                    ])->alignCenter()
                ])
            ])
            ->filters([
                //
            ])
            ->actions([
                EditAction::make(),
                Tables\Actions\Action::make('Details')->button() //->url(route(''))
            ])
            ->bulkActions([
                Tables\Actions\DeleteBulkAction::make(),
            ]);
    }
```

I have tried to look it up but I have found nothing interesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the documentation: https://filamentphp.com/docs/3.x/panels/installation

**`php artisan filament:install --panels`**

This will create and register a new Laravel service provider called **`app/Providers/Filament/AdminPanelProvider.php`**.

In this file, you must comment the relevant line:

```
->pages([
            // Pages\Dashboard::class,
        ])
```

Comment: When I remove the line it errors. I want a simple landing page for the panel, any idea how to show a page I created directly?

Answer (score 0):

In `config/filament.php`, you should see something like this:

```
'pages' => [
    'namespace' => 'App\\Filament\\Pages',
    'path' => app_path('Filament/Pages'),
    'register' => [
        Pages\Dashboard::class,
    ],
],
```

Comment out or remove that `Pages\Dashboard::class` line.

Comment: <?php

return [


    'broadcasting' => [

    ],


    'default_filesystem_disk' => env('FILAMENT_FILESYSTEM_DISK', 'public'),

]

Comment: Thats my file /config/filament

Comment: @VlajicStevan Which Filament version are you on? In v3, it's a little different; https://filamentphp.com/docs/3.x/panels/configuration and https://filamentphp.com/docs/3.x/panels/dashboard#customizing-the-dashboard-page

Comment: im in version 3.0: "filament/filament": "3.0",